# Ruby on Rails: Using Collection_select and edit path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble getting this to work. What I want to do is have a dropdown that populates with team numbers, then depending on which one the user selects it takes them to the edit page for that team. I can get the dropdown to populate correctly, but I can not get it to take me to the correct page. When I test it a different way, it does take me to the correct page so I don't believe that it is a routing error.

The code with issues:

```
<%= form_tag edit_corevalue_path(@corevalue), method: 'get' do %>
<%= collection_select(:corevalue, :corevalue_id, Corevalue.all, :id, :teamNumber, :prompt => "Select Team") %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit!", :name => nil , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I get the error:
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"corevalues", :id=>nil}

But if I comment that out and test it with:

```
<%= link_to "TEST", edit_corevalue_path(2) %>
```

Then it works and takes me to the correct page. I believe the error is that it is not getting the correct id when using @corevalue, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it or what the proper syntax would be. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `:id` instead of `:corevalue_id` as the 2nd argument to the collection_select function:

```
<%= collection_select(:corevalue, :id, Corevalue.all, :id, :teamNumber, :prompt => "Select Team") %>
```

[See ActionView reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)